Getting Sonarr to work with qbittorrent using vpn and traefik
Currently trying to setup traefik to run with sonarr and qbittorrent using wireguard. With my setup all 3 services are setup via traefik and they are all accessible in same t2_proxy network. qbitorrent runs via wireguard while sonarr doesn't. When setting up qbittorrent client via sonarr UI it asks for name and port when i enter domain and port + credentials however testing configuration does not succeed.
qbittorrent:
 image: lscr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent
 container_name: qbittorrent
 restart: unless-stopped
 network_mode: 'service:wireguard'
 environment:
   - PUID=$PUID
   - PGID=$PGID
   - TZ=$TZ
   - WEBUI_PORT=$QBITTORRENT_PORT
 volumes:
   - '$USERDIR/docker/qbittorrent/config:/config'
   - '$USERDIR/docker/jellyfin/downloads:/downloads'
 labels:
   - traefik.enable=true
   - traefik.http.routers.qbittorrent-rtr.entrypoints=https
   - traefik.http.routers.qbittorrent-rtr.rule=Host(`qbittorrent.$DOMAINNAME`)
   - traefik.http.routers.qbittorrent-rtr.tls=true
   - traefik.http.routers.qbittorrent-rtr.service=qbittorrent-svc
   - traefik.http.services.qbittorrent-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9864
   - traefik.http.routers.qbittorrent-rtr.middlewares=redirect-to-domain@file

sonarr:
 image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sonarr:latest
 container_name: sonarr
 networks:
   - t2_proxy
 environment:
   - PUID=$PUID
   - PGID=$PGID
   - TZ=$TZ
 volumes:
   - '$USERDIR/docker/sonarr/data:/config'
   - '$USERDIR/docker/jellyfin/tv:/tv'
   - '$USERDIR/docker/jellyfin/downloads:/downloads'
 ports:
   - '$SONARR_PORT:8989'
 restart: unless-stopped
 labels:
   - traefik.enable=true
   - traefik.http.routers.sonarr-rtr.entrypoints=https
   - traefik.http.routers.sonarr-rtr.rule=Host(`sonarr.$DOMAINNAME`)
   - traefik.http.routers.sonarr-rtr.tls=true
   - traefik.http.routers.sonarr-rtr.service=sonarr-svc
   - traefik.http.services.sonarr-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=8989

wireguard:
 image: linuxserver/wireguard:latest
 container_name: wireguard
 restart: unless-stopped
 networks:
   - t2_proxy
 cap_add:
   - NET_ADMIN
   - SYS_MODULE #optional
 environment:
   - PUID=$PUID
   - PGID=$PGID
   - TZ=$TZ
   - SERVERURL=wireguard.domain #optional
   - PEERS=1
   - SERVERPORT=$WIREGUARD_PORT #optional
   - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
   - LOG_LEVEL=debug
 volumes:
   - '$USERDIR/docker/wireguard/config:/config'
   - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
 ports:
   - '$QBITTORRENT_PORT:9864'
   - '$TORRENT_PORT:8999'
 sysctls:
   - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
 labels:
   - traefik.enable=true
   - traefik.udp.routers.wireguard-rtr.entrypoints=wireguard
   - traefik.udp.routers.wireguard-rtr.service=wireguard-svc
   - traefik.udp.services.wireguard-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=51820
 dns:
   - 8.8.8.8
   - 1.1.1.1`

And middleware i tried:
[http.middlewares.redirect-to-domain.redirectRegex]
regex = "(https?://[^:]+):[0-9]+"
replacement = "${1}"
permanent = true

Confirmed that if I curl https://qbitorrent.domain.com it resolves corrently however if i do https://qbittorrent.comain.com:9864 which is qbitorrent port it does not resolve. What am I doing wrong here? I also tried to setup a redirect middleware to redirect domain:port to domain but that didnt work either.
